# Value Error trying to get data from mysql in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-views

I'm running a `django` app and I've implemented MySQL. When I run the server and try to load the page I get the error "badly formed hexadecimal UUID string." This occurs in the `uuid.py` file in **init** at line 140 and from what I can tell, this occurs because the value `hex` is not of length 32 but I don't know how to address this issue.
This is the model that the entries in the database follow.

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.db.models import (
    UUIDField,
    CharField,
    TextField,
    IntegerField,
    DecimalField,
    ImageField
)
# Create your models here.

class AnimeCatalog(models.Model):
    anime_id = UUIDField(primary_key = True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = CharField(max_length=300)
    genre = CharField(max_length=300)
    typeanime = CharField(max_length = 10)
    episodes = IntegerField(default=0)
    rating = DecimalField(max_digits = 4, decimal_places = 2, null = True)
    members = IntegerField()
    anime_cover = ImageField(blank = True, null = True, upload_to = "img/animeCover", verbose_name = "Profile Photo")
```

Then I try to call the objects.all() method on this model to retrieve it from mysql in the views.py file which is below

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from .forms import AnimeCatalogForm
from .models import AnimeCatalog
from .WebScraping import findAnimePic
import csv
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    temp = []
    tempID = []
    pics = []
    fiveNames = []
    names = []

    new = AnimeCatalog.objects.all()

    for line in new:
        temp.append(line['name'].replace('&#039;', ''))
        tempID.append(line['anime_id'])

    for x in range(0,5):
        pics.append(findAnimePic(tempID[x],temp[x]))

    for x in range(0, len(temp), 5):
        for y in range (5):
            if not(x+y >= len(temp)):
                fiveNames.append({'name':temp[x+y],'img':pics[y]})
        names.append(fiveNames)
        fiveNames = []
    items = {'names': names, 'imgs': pics}
    html = render(request, 'home/home.html', {'names':names})
    return html
```

Also this is a picture of the first few entries in the mysql which i imported a csv file.
[Image of mysql database with imported csv files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipp8o.png)

Answer (score 0):

As is clear from that screenshot, `anime_id` contains integers, not UUIDs. I don't know why you set it to be a UUIDField but you should use AutoField instead and remove the default.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and get back to you. I set it as UUID because i recently started learning Django so i was following partly with a slide.